# laravel 7 installation

Tags: php, sql, laravel

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 blog` using this command and I got error this

> [InvalidArgumentException]   Could not find package laravel/laravel
> with version 7.0 in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP
> exte   nsions and Composer version.

Comment: Make sure your computer/system meet the requirement for laravel 7.0. Refer to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#server-requirements) to know what are the requirements

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP Version is not compatible with your Laravel version, If you are using `XAMPP` or other web servers, try to use the older version that is compatible with your `Laravel-7` project file, and after that reinstall your `Laravel-7` project.

Answer (score -1):

Your PHP version is not compatible with Laravel version 7.0

[Laravel 7 Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#server-requirements)
Laravel 7 requires PHP >= 7.2.5. Check your php version using `php -v` on terminal.

You can uninstall `composer` then again install it.

Comment: It will remove the installed version.

Comment: Uninstalling composer itself will not touch any files, only it's executable. Maybe you mean `composer update`/`composer install`?